# Best data type for PostgreSQL datatime type

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Actually I have:

```
CREATE TABLE public.user(
  id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
  nick VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  born DATE,
  joined DATE,
  tags text[]
);
```

I want to choose best option to save register time, and born data. I searched internet but didnt find any good results.
Maybe its better to use time from python, and just insert it to postgres?

Comment: Tell us a bit more about what you want to do with this action. Are you managing database from SQL plain or using an ORM from Python?

Comment: So are you asking for the best way to store the Postgres date type in a python variable is?

Comment: @JuanCastaño now im creating database structure, so just typing SQL, without python. 

 im not sure, should i use database time, or python system time.

Comment: @K-Log  im not sure, should i use database time, or python system time.

Comment: Why not just store the date as string in python?

Comment: @K-Log im not sure if this is the best option. Thats reason why im asking :-) f.e. if i want find all data from september all years, or segregate data, string can be not the best. Isnt there specify kind of pole to store data?

Comment: Your question is confusing. You want to insert the time and you want to choose the datatype. Isn't timestamp without zone enough for you?

Comment: Well it depends on what you want to do with it. For example, if you use python’s `datetime` object it allows for easy manipulation and accessing of specific components of the object such as just the weekday or the year.

Comment: @mad_ sorry my bad, im building service only for one country, so timezone is not important. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the **birth date** you don't need the time of the day, so a `DATE` would be appropriate.

For the **registration date** you probably would like to save the date and time. In this case `TIMESTAMP` would be more appropriate.

Avoid using `VARCHAR` to store dates. Since it doesn't validate anything, it will allow you to store bad information and you won't be able to compute any information on them easily. For example:

- Bad string value #1: `35-jan-2017`: this date does not exist.
- Bad string value #2: `10-12-99`: is it 10 of December, or 12 of October?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to store the plain time without timezone simply use `timestamp` probaböy useful for creation time or so on.
And for columns like birthdate, just use Date

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need define how often you will change your database structure (adding or removing recordes). I would recommend you use an ORM for this boilerplate task like SQLAlchemy or PonyORM and avoiding manipulate database directly.

Answering your question:
Whether you want add timestamp to any field, a trigger often would be useful for this task.

You always use:

**Date** data type for dates that it doesn't require specific moment in a time like birthday date, published post (on a blog).

**Timestamp** for specific moments like register in an app, managing login apps, transactional records, etc.

Never merge code for both parts, so whether you decide manage database from Python code, you should use only Python code.

In same sense, whether you decide manage tables and action on database, only use triggers and objects from database for this task.

I hope your question was answered!